# NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with two types of persistent stores?

Tags: ios, core-data

In an iOS app, I would like to use an `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` with both an `NSIncrementalStore` subclass, for fetching data from a REST API, but also with an SQLite store, to save to disk. If I add both types of persistent stores to my coordinator, however, calling `save:` on my managed object context has no effect. If I only add the one persistent store, not of the type for my `NSIcrementalStore` subclass, then the save works as intended.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best solution in my experience is to have multiple managed object contexts, each having its own model.

However, there is a way to accomplish what you want:

```
// create the store coordinator
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *storeCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] init];
// create the first store
NSPersistentStore *firstStore = [storeCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType: NSIncrementalStore configuration:nil URL:urlToFirstStore options:optionsForFirstStore error:&error];
// now create the second one
NSPersistentStore *secondStore = [storeCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStore configuration:nil URL:urlToSecondStore options:optionsForSecondStore error:&error];

// Now you have two stores and one context
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:storeCoordinator];

// and you can assign your entities to different stores like this
NSManagedObject *someObject = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:someEntity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
// here the relevant part
[context assignObject:someObject toPersistentStore:firstStore]; // or secondStore ..
```

You should also check these links to get a better idea about how Core Data works:

[Core Data Programming Guide - Persistent Store Coordinator](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001650-SW4)

[SO: Two persistent stores for one managed object context - possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5399543/719656)

[SO: Can two managed object context share one single persistent store coordinator?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2990843/719656)

Also check the comment by TechZen in the second link about configurations and read about it in here:

[Core Data Programming Guide - Configurations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMOM.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002328-SW3)

and here is a nice tutorial to manage two object contexts:

[Multiple Managed Object Contexts with Core Data](http://www.timisted.net/blog/archive/multiple-managed-object-contexts-with-core-data/)

Comment: Thank you, I’ve set up everything properly thanks to those resources. However, one question remains: I have multiple managed object contexts, but a single persistent store coordinator with two persistent stores. When I perform a fetch request on my main managed object context, I only want that to be associated with my SQLite persistent store, and not use my NSIncrementalStore subclass. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Looks like it’s `-[NSFetchRequest setAffectedStores:]`.

Comment: @JordanKay You're welcome. Sorry I didn't answer your question about the fetch request earlier, it's sunny and hot here so I was partying :). But it looks like you got it right! [NSFetchRequest setAffectedStores:] it is.